# Symfony2 ignores routing defaults cache control

Tags: php, symfony

In my `routing.yml` file I have the following definition according to [the doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html):

```
webservice_resources:
    path: /webservice/resources
    defaults:
        _controller: FooBarCogsBaseBundle:Resources:getResourcesByTags
        maxAge: 3600
        shareMaxAge: 3600
```

But the response headers indicate that these settings are ignored:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

I am expecting to see something more along the lines of this:

```
Cache-Control: public,max-age=3600,s-maxage=3600
```

Why would Symfony2 ignore the cache defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is based purely around static templates.

example in the symfony2 docs (you are not using a template, you are rendering a dynamic page it appears though):

```
acme_privacy:
    path: /privacy
    defaults:
        _controller:  FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:     'static/privacy.html.twig'
        maxAge:       86400
        sharedAge:    86400
```

What you want is something like this (from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response();

// mark the response as either public or private
$response->setPublic();
$response->setPrivate();

// set the private or shared max age
$response->setMaxAge(600);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(600);
```

Or per that same documentation:

`If you need to set cache headers for many different controller actions, you might want to look into the FOSHttpCacheBundle.`

Which is located at http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: This is precisely what I came-up with as well, and you are correct, I am using a different non-template controller.